# Решение проблемы подключения внешнего USB устройства (ADALM2000) к планшету с Android 9

Tags: android

Устройство ADALM2000 не опознаётся драйвером USB порта планшета Huawei MediaPad m5 CMR-AL09 (Android 9 сборка 9.1.0.381(c10e8r1p5)). Режим OTG с другими внешними устройствами работает,кабель исправен,порт ADALM2000 исправен (проверен со смартфоном (Android 12)и приложением Scopy для ADALM2000) В режиме отладка по USB планшет не позволяет включить передачу файлов. Что можно исправить в ядре Android?